# Does non-matter energy curve spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, energy, spacetime, curvature

I know that matter (mass) curves spacetime, but do other forms of energy do the same? I.e. is matter the only form of energy that curves spacetime?

Comment: Yes, every type of energy.

Comment: see [this picture from wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/StressEnergyTensor_contravariant.svg/640px-StressEnergyTensor_contravariant.svg.png) - anything that's in there has an effect on space-time geometry

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22876/2451 and links therein.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the factors affecting the spacetime curvature?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103918/)